# Is there a general way to index in jQuery? I know there's .first() but how about .second() or .third()

Tags: jquery

This seems like a pretty simple question but I honestly couldn't find an answer. I have 3 forms on my side that open up when a button is pressed and I want to autofocus a cursor on whichever one of the forms opens up. Because the forms are identical, I'm having trouble referencing any individual one, and it's on Squarespace so I can't just add an id. I would be really grateful for any help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`.eq()` method](https://api.jquery.com/eq/). Just supply an index (they are zero based).

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the [`.eq()` method](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the set.